# TypeError in Numpy when using custom datatype

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning numpy using [this book](http://www.packtpub.com/numpy-mathematical-2e-beginners-guide/book). However, in one of the assignments I'm having this error:

```
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

This is my code:

```
record = dtype([('name', 'str_', 40), ('stock', 'int32'), ('price', 'float32')])
items = array(['Book A', 5, 29.95], dtype=record)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using numpy array, you should create a list of tuples rather a tuple of lists. Numpy array expects a list of tuples. Hope, the following solves your issue.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> record = np.dtype([('name', 'str_', 40), ('stock', 'int32'), ('price', 'float32')])
>>> var=[('Book A', 5, 29.95)]
>>> items = np.array(var, dtype=record)
>>> items
array([('Book A', 5, 29.950000762939453)],
      dtype=[('name', '|S40'), ('stock', '<i4'), ('price', '<f4')])
>>>
```

Comment: That what I told in my answer!

Comment: How weird. On my tablet I only saw your code without the accompanying text in your answer.

Comment: Refreshing the page could be helpful I guess! 
@Praetore: If the answer was helpful, why don't you accept and upvote it so that people would not ask the same/similar question in future? Cheers!